# Secondary link `onclick` event not being called

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following code and I am trying to call `Floater.Create()` on `click` of the `[data-floatertype=minimize]` object. I do not want to use IDs, just work through the DOM. FYI the `[data-floatertype=minimize]` object already has a `.on('click',...)` attached to it, I would like it to do both.

```
<div data-floater="true" data-minimized="false">
    <p data-floatertype="title" class="title" style="font-size: 20px;">Welcome</p>
    <a data-floatertype="minimize" href="#" class="minimize" style="right: 30px;">-</a>  
    <a href="#" data-floatertype="close" class="close">X</a>
    <div data-floatertype="content" class="content" style="display: block;">                
    <div style="display: block; text-align: center;" data-display="block">
        <h3>Floaters 101</h3>
        <hr>
        <p style="text-align:left;">You can have as many floaters open as you would like.</p>
        <p style="text-align:left;">Floaters can be minimized by using the minimize button in the top right.</p>
        <p style="text-align:left;">Floaters can also be closed using the close button in the top right.</p>
        <hr>
        <p>Try minimizing this window now.</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(this).parent().siblings('[data-floatertype=minimize]').on('click', function () {
                Floater.Create("Good job!", "floatertutorial.php", {intro: "3"});
            });
        </script>
    </div>              
</div>
```

My suspected problem is that `$(this).parent().siblings(...)` isn't returning the right object, or possibly nothing at all. Or... the `.on('click',...)` isn't binding correctly. In any case the `Floater.Create()` method is not called when the link is clicked. Help?

Comment: The way you are using it `this` is the global object `window`. You need to pas a CSS selector to the `$` to get a selection.

Comment: Indeed where you put it, $(this) will return nothing... so has no siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't affected by the 'scope' of your HTML elements, `this` refers to `window` where you've used it. You will need to do it something like this:

```
$('[data-floatertype=minimize]').on('click', function () {
    Floater.Create("Good job!", "floatertutorial.php", {intro: "3"});
});
```